# How to sort web2py Grid rows by multiple fields?

Tags: sql-order-by, web2py

Web2py newbie here.

Given the below Web2py model controller and view, how would I make Web2py display in the resulting view (`index.html`) the grid ordered by `manufacturer` first and by `commercial_name` second?

#### Model: `dy.py`

```
db.define_table('item',
    Field('manufacturer', db.business_partner, label = 'manufacturer'),
    Field('commercial_name', required=True, label = 'commercial name'),
    Field('technical_data_sheet', 'upload', label = 'tds'),
    format='%(manufacturer)s %(commercial_name)s')
```

#### Controller: `default.py`

```
def item():
    grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.item)
    return dict(grid=grid)
```

#### View: `item.html`

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h2>items and manufcaturer</h2>
{{=grid}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `orderby` option of `SQLFORM.grid()`. And you can sort multiple fields by concatenating them with a "|".

So in your case, grid definition will be:

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.item, orderby=db.item.manufacturer|db.item.commercial_name)
```

Read [Grid Signature](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORMgrid-signature) and [orderby](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#orderby)

Comment: Thanks, it works beautifully. What if though, I had to sort "db.item.commercial_name" in descending (DESC) order?

Comment: @JoeCarpenter use unary operator "`~`", like this `orderby=~db.item.commercial_name`